# get combobox value in datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

For example i have table configuration like this

**id | name | stats**

where **stats** is a combobox, that have 2 option

```
<select name="yourOpt">
<option value="0">Not Active</option>
<option value="1">Active</option>
</select>
```

for example my data is:

```
1 | David | Active
2 | James | Not Active
```

How to get the value 1 of "Active" for data 1 and get value - of Not Active for data2 from that combobox?

Thanks Before

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will answer your question.

`$( "select[name='yourOpt']" ).change(function() {
  var selected = $('select').val()
});`

i would be adding id's to my inputs so it will be more focused

Answer (score 0):

> $("select[name='yourOpt']" ).change(function() {
>   console.log($(this).Val()) });

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified at what point you want get the values from the combo boxes (for example after an option was select - as mentioned in the other answers), I will post a solution that lets you obtain the value of the combo box in a row, specified by it's index in the table body.

The code uses jQuery and Javascript.

```
function getSelectedOptionInRow(index){
    let selector = "tbody tr:nth-child(" + (index+1) + ") select option:selected";
    return $(selector).val();
}
```

You can use this function as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>stats</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>David</td>
        <td>
          <select name="yourOpt">
            <option value="0">Not Active</option>
            <option value="1">Active</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>
          <select name="yourOpt">
            <option value="0">Not Active</option>
            <option value="1">Active</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button onclick="btnClicked()">Click</button>

  <script>

    // Action when button is clicked
    function btnClicked() {
      printAll();
    }

    // Helper function to get the options
    // in all the rows
    function printAll() {
      let selector = "tbody tr"
      let options = [];
      $(selector).each(function(i) {
        options.push(getSelectedOptionInRow(i));
      });
      alert(options.join(" "));
    }

    // Function to obtain the selected id
    // of the 'yourOpt' combobox.
    function getSelectedOptionInRow(index) {
      let selector = "tbody tr:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + ") select option:selected";
      return $(selector).val();
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```